# Set anonymous type to null

Tags: c#, linq, try-catch, anonymous-types

I know it's not allowed to set an nonymous type to null, but how do I solve this:

```
var products = null; //this cant be null, but somehow it must be declared in this outer scope, and not only inside the try-catch scope

    try
     {
         products = (from p in repository.Products
                     select new { p.Product, p.ProductName }).ToList();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {  
       return;
     }
Console.WriteLine(products.FirstOrDefault().ProductName)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with the other answers that you should consider refactoring this code or using a nominal type rather than an anonymous type.

However, there is a way to get a null reference in a variable of anonymous type. It's easy.

```
static List<T> GimmeANullListOf<T>(T t) { return (List<T>)null; }
...
var products = GimmeANullListOf(new { X = 1, Y = "hello" });
```

This trick is called "cast by example", and it is weird but legal.

Comment: But it takes internal knowledge of the compiler into account, which might not be true for other compilers or for future versions of the compiler. (Of course, _you_ can make it true for the Microsoft C# compiler...) Or ... is it somewhere in the spec? Would it work across assemblies?

Comment: @Jordão: I'm not following you. How does it take internal knowledge of the compiler into account? This is legal C# and any conforming implementation needs to have this behaviour. Why do you believe that this is implementation-defined behaviour? What does "would it work across assemblies?" mean? I don't understand what 'work across' means in your question.

Comment: @Jordão: If by "work across assemblies" you mean could you have two methods in two assemblies that both return "identical" objects of anonymous type, could you treat them as the same type, then no. The C# spec states that anonymous types are only guaranteed to unify within a single compilation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And thanks for the information that the spec does mention that the types are unified, that's what I wanted to know. I knew about this technique before, it's just that I didn't know how official it was. +1 for it.

Comment: @Jordão: See section 7.6.10.6 of the C# 4 specification. "Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify a sequence of properties of the same names and compile-time types in the same order will produce instances of the same anonymous type."

Answer (score 5):

Or `new Nullable<bool>()` will get the job done nicely.

Answer (score 2):

For something that simple, and for the fact that you `return` on exception, you should be able to just do everything in the `try` block instead of having to declare `products` outside it:

```
try
{
    var products = (from p in repository.Products
                    select new { p.Product, p.ProductName }).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(products.FirstOrDefault().ProductName);
}
catch (Exception e)
{  
    return;
}
```

Although I agree very much with SLaks, you shouldn't swallow exceptions and return like that.

Comment: Yes indeed it will. The code is simplified, I thought that was clear enough.. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple way round that. Your choices are either to change the control flow to wrap the whole thing in your `try{}` block (trivial in this case, but I assume this code is simplified for illustrative purposes), or do declare a concrete type such as

```
class ProductWithName
{
    public int Product;
    public string ProductName;
}
```

and then use

```
List<ProductWithName> products = null;
```

and

```
select new ProductWithName { Product = p.Product, ProductName = p.ProductName }
```

Which is the best option really depends on what your real code looks like.

Comment: You are right, the code is heavily simplified, and I thought of this solution myself. However, I wanted to avoid making a new class just for this. But this would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the anonymous type that can't be null, it's the `IEnumerable<T>`(or IQueryable) that must not be null since you iterate over it.

You can use `products ?? Enumerable.Empty<Product>()` to replace null by an empty `IEnumerable<T>`.

And don't swallow exceptions like that. Catching the `Exception` base-class is only a good idea in very specific scenarios, and yours isn't one of them.

Comment: I believe this require a dedicated Product-class, which I wanted to avoid. My code is heavily simplified, so I understand why you picked the Product-class approach though.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use an anonymous type outside its declaring scope.

You can do it with reflection:

```
IEnumerable<object> products = null;

// ...

var anon = products.FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(anon.GetType().GetProperty("ProductName").GetValue(anon, null));
```

Or dynamic:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> products = null;

// ...

var anon = products.FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(anon.ProductName);
```

Comment: This is cool, haven't tested it though, but it seems legit. But because of performance reasons, this can't be used in this case.

Comment: The performance characteristics of `dynamic` might [surprise you](http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/06/26/c-4.0-dynamics-vs.-reflection.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since LINQ has deferred execution you can define the query in the parent scope and run it in the try catch block like so:

```
var productsDB = new List<Func<string>>() { () => "Apples", () => "Pears", () => "Bannanas" };//, () => { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }; // sorry, couldn't think of a better way to make this fail in 2 mins..

var products = (
    from p in productsDB
    select new 
    {
        Name = p()
    } );

try
{
    products.ToList(); // runs the LINQ query
    products.Dump();   // prints the results (LINQPad)
}
catch { "there was an error".Dump(); }
```

Or another option is the Tuple class, which is excellent for this kind of thing:

```
var productsDB = new[] { "Apples", "Pears",  "Bannanas" };

List<Tuple<string>> products;

try
{
    products = (
        from p in productsDB
        select Tuple.Create( p ) ).ToList();

    products.Dump();
}
catch { "there was an error".Dump(); }

// Build anonymous type from (read-only) Tuple here if necessary...
```

---

**EDIT:** Just realised I mis-read the post :p - heres my original post:

I think it's just the type-checker complaining, try something like this..

```
var employees = (
    from person in db.denormalisedPeople
    where person.Type == "employee"
    select new
    {
        name = employee.FullName,
        areaID = new Nullable<int>(), // placeholder.. set in a future query                
    } ).ToList();
```

(untested code, but the technique works fine for me)